# How @Caching version was bound to JPA entity version(optimistic lock)?

Tags: spring, jpa, caching, version

I use spring @Version for optimistic lock, and I use @Caching to cache the jpa entity. the version in database was auto incremented when the transaction was committed, but the version in cache was not been incremented.  How could I keep them consistent whenever the transaction is committed or rollback?

Comment: Which `@Caching` annotation, if this is from Spring, don't use it to cache entities, or be very cautious and add the `@CacheEvict` everywhere. I would suggest not to use it and let the 2nd level caching handle this instead.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum  , Thanks for your reply,  Do you think 2nd level caching possible leads to inconsistent cache  between multi instance?

Comment: If you have multiple instances you need a shared/distributed cache.